# any opensource scripting language with ide + debugger? (for use in a c++ project)

Tags: scripting, open-source, ide

we have written a bit of an application framework (game engine really, but that's not important) in C++, and would like to extend functionality by a more RAD friendly scripting environment.

So we are looking for a (or multiple) scripting language that is

1. open source (free: mono is not free on different platforms)
2. has an IDE (intelisence, for accessible classes/methods)
3. has runtime debugging support.  (breakpoints, and variable inspection at a minimum)
4. can integrate with a C++ project

anything out there meet these needs?

Comment: search for that looks kind of interesting, but not sure it's what i need because i'm looking for an IDE to write this stuff in.    For example, if I used mono, i could set a breakpoint (in the script) and then attach Visual Studio or MonoDevelop to the process and start debugging.

unfortunatly mono isn't an option because of it's license fee on different platforms

Comment: I found two potentials for LUA.   if anyone else has suggestions i'd like to know:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808361/recommendations-for-a-lua-ide-and-debugger-on-windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143939/whats-a-good-ide-to-use-for-lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've indicated your interest in Lua, I'll expand on that a bit. Using Lua takes care of #1 (open source) and #4 (C++ integration).

The two projects I've been working on *may* take care of #2 -- [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) is a lightweight open-source Lua IDE, and #3 -- [MobDebug](https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug) is a Lua debugger, also open-source, also on github, and integrates with ZeroBrane Studio. ZeroBrane Studio runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux..

Comment: great, thanks for the update, seems like a good choice for me to try!